method parameters being allocated within a method
I was surprised about this behaviour in C#:
public class A
{
    public void Mt1(User user)
    {
        user.Name= "Brekeke";
    }

    public void Mt2(User user)
    {
        user = new ();
    }
}


[TestMethod]
public void TEST_DEBUG()
{
    User user1 = new();
    new A().Mt1(user1);
    Assert.IsTrue(user1.Name == "Brekeke"); // OK

    User user2 = null;
    new A().Mt2(user2);
    Assert.IsNotNull(user2); // Fails!
}

I understand that the Mt1 works as expected.
Methods parameters are references in C#.
But I am surprised that the test of the second method fails.
I was mistakenely assuming that the variable user2, used as a method parameter (so being a reference), would keep the value allocated within the method after the method returns??
Why isn't it the case?

I'm sure there's a duplicate that I haven't found yet, but essentially... The two examples do two very different things.  The first one mutates an object.  It's still the same object, and it doesn't matter how many different variables reference that object, you're just setting a property on that one object in memory.  The second example assigns a new value to the local user variable in the method.  The object from the test method still exists and the variable user2 still references it.  But the variable user inside the method now references a new and entirely different object.

C# passes "pointers" to classes by value. If you wanted to modify the variable user2, you'd have to pass using the ref keyword
